# How to delete generated bitstreams in DSpace 6x?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, dspace

I would like to delete all the bitstreams generated by filter-media but only with a specific description **"IM Thumbnail"**.

[image: Item Bitstreams]

I am aware that I can just regenerate the thumbnail by using the `-f` flag to force it to regenerate the thumbnail. I am testing some settings in my setup and I would just like to delete the generated thumbnails with this specific description first.

I've tried tinkering the database via PgAdmin but I can only go as far as selecting the bitstreams. I don't even know how to group or order the returned results and not really sure if I've selected the correct tables.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  public.bitstream, 
  public.bundle, 
  public.bundle2bitstream, 
  public.metadatavalue, 
  public.item2bundle
WHERE 
  bitstream.uuid = metadatavalue.dspace_object_id AND
  bitstream.uuid = bundle2bitstream.bitstream_id AND
  bundle.uuid = item2bundle.bundle_id AND
  bundle2bitstream.bundle_id = bundle.uuid AND
  metadatavalue.text_value = 'IM Thumbnail';
```

Any advice on how to do this via database manipulation or any other means would be greatly appreciated. Applying the SQL deletion within a specific community or collection would be a really nice bonus too!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question was tagged with postgresql, I found the answer from DSpace Community Mailing List using Jython. Thanks for Joan Caparros for the original code. The message thread can be found here: [Removing Thumbnails in DSpace 5](https://groups.google.com/g/dspace-community/c/2sSQ0YixaG8/m/bu6MIIMoFQAJ). I also posted a similar query in the DSpace Technical Support Mailing List which can be found here: [Batch delete bitstreams in the Bundle: THUMBNAIL](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dspace-tech/l92kk4nvotU/dgz510hRBAAJ) where Joan posted a modified version of his [code](https://github.com/kerojohan/curation_taks/blob/master/ctscripts/deletingTHUMBNAILS.py) for my specific needs which is deleting only the thumbnails if it contains the description "IM Thumbnail". Below is the full code that achieved my goals:

```
from org.dspace.curate import ScriptedTask
from org.dspace.curate import Curator
from org.dspace.content.service import DSpaceObjectService
from org.dspace.content.factory import ContentServiceFactory

#from org.dspace.content.service import BitstreamService

class Main(ScriptedTask):
    def init(self, curator, taskName):
        print "initializing with Jython"

    def performDso(self, dso):
        #print "perform on dso "
        if dso.getType()==2:
            print "Item '" + dso.getName() + "' ("+dso.getHandle()+")"
            myBundles = dso.itemService.getBundles(dso,"THUMBNAIL")
            totalbundles = len(myBundles)
            for i in myBundles:
                myBitstreams = i.getBitstreams()
                total = len(myBitstreams)
                if len(myBitstreams)==0:
                    print "- DELETING EMPTY BUNDLE"
            dso.itemService.removeBundle(Curator.curationContext(),dso,myBundles[0])
            if len(myBitstreams)>0:
                for k in range(0,len(myBitstreams)):
                    if myBitstreams[k].getDescription() == 'IM Thumbnail':
                        print "DELETE "+myBitstreams[0].getDescription()
                        bitstreamService = ContentServiceFactory.getInstance().getBitstreamService()
                        bitstreamService.delete(Curator.curationContext(),myBitstreams[0])
                        print "- DELETING BUNDLE"
                        dso.itemService.removeBundle(Curator.curationContext(),dso,myBundles[0])
        return 0

    def performId(self, context, id):
        print "perform on id %s" % (id)
        return 0
```

Please note that the code above was made as a curation task using Jython so the documentation on how to set up and use can be found here: [Curation tasks in Jython](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/Curation+tasks+in+Jython).